# How would I fix #block_two div in place? I've tried using the position property but that didn't work

Tags: html, css

I've tried position referencing to fix the position of "#block_two" but that doesn't seem to work. The div disappears when I use fix and absolute isn't better. I also tried changing the z-index of #block_two but to no avail.

```css
    html {
    overflow: scroll;

    }

    body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;

    }

    div#static_nav{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #3A3D3F;
    position:fixed;
    opacity: .90;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;

    }

    div#static_nav a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .navbar {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    }

    div#container {
    margin-top: 10px
    height: 10vh
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #16BA81;
    color:;
    }

    div#block_two{
    background-color: ;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(/New_Website/sample_image.png);
    background-size: cover;
    }

    div#block_three{
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #E4E2E2;

    }

    div#column-left{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div#column-right{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div#column-center{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div#block_four{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #E4E2E2;
    }

    div#end_block{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .area_content{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3A3D3F;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .eb_header{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #3A3D3F;
    }

    .b3_pics{
    max-width: inherit;
    height: 50%;
    }

    .b4{
    padding-top: 60px;
    max-width: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #3A3D3F;
    }

    .b3_hd{
    color: #3A3D3F;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
      <header>
      <div id="static_nav">
        <nav class='navbar'>
          <a href="#block_two">HOME</a>
          <a href="#block_three">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="#block_four">PEOPLE</a>
          <a href="#end_block">CONTACT</a>
          <a href="Member Login">LOG IN</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id="block_two">
    </div>

    <div id="block_three">

      <div id="column-left">
        <header class="b3_hd">
          Hospitality
        </header>
        <div class="b3_pics">
          <div id="pic1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="area_content">
          
        </p>
        </div>

      <div id="column-center">
        <header class="b3_hd">
        COLUMN CENTER
        </header>
        <div class="b3_pics">
          <div id="pic2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="area_content">
        </p>
      </div>

      <div id="column-right">
        <header class="b3_hd">
          COLUMN RIGHT
        </header>
        <div class="b3_pics">
          <div id="pic3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="area_content">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="block_four">
      <header class="b4"> PEOPLE </header>
    </div>

    <div id="end_block">
      <header class="eb_header">
        CONTACT
      </header>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where do you want to fix this `#block_two`

Comment: I want that div to remain where it is as it will have a background image.  The other div should scroll over it. @AnujaAgarwal

Comment: and by scroll over you mean over it or below it.

Comment: scroll over.  for example block_three, block_four and end_block should scroll over block_two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:fixed;` and a negative `z-index`

```css
html {
    overflow: scroll;

    }

    body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
      padding:100vh 0 0 0;

    }

    div#static_nav{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: #3A3D3F;
    position:fixed;
    opacity: .90;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
      top:0;
    z-index:999;
    }

    div#static_nav a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    }

    .navbar {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    }

    div#container {
    margin-top: 10px
    height: 10vh
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #16BA81;
    color:;
    }

    div#block_two{
    background-color: ;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    position:fixed;
      top:2.5em;
    z-index:-1;
      width:100%;
    }

    div#block_three{
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #E4E2E2;

    }

    div#column-left{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div#column-right{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div#column-center{
    padding-top: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    div#block_four{
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #E4E2E2;
    }

    div#end_block{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .area_content{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3A3D3F;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .eb_header{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #3A3D3F;
    }

    .b3_pics{
    max-width: inherit;
    height: 50%;
    }

    .b4{
    padding-top: 60px;
    max-width: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #3A3D3F;
    }

    .b3_hd{
    color: #3A3D3F;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
      <header>
      <div id="static_nav">
        <nav class='navbar'>
          <a href="#block_two">HOME</a>
          <a href="#block_three">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="#block_four">PEOPLE</a>
          <a href="#end_block">CONTACT</a>
          <a href="Member Login">LOG IN</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div id="block_two">
    </div>

    <div id="block_three">

      <div id="column-left">
        <header class="b3_hd">
          Hospitality
        </header>
        <div class="b3_pics">
          <div id="pic1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="area_content">
          
        </p>
        </div>

      <div id="column-center">
        <header class="b3_hd">
        COLUMN CENTER
        </header>
        <div class="b3_pics">
          <div id="pic2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="area_content">
        </p>
      </div>

      <div id="column-right">
        <header class="b3_hd">
          COLUMN RIGHT
        </header>
        <div class="b3_pics">
          <div id="pic3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="area_content">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="block_four">
      <header class="b4"> PEOPLE </header>
    </div>

    <div id="end_block">
      <header class="eb_header">
        CONTACT
      </header>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: see the results in full page. it's not scrolling in this snippet runner. Don't forget to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help it works in the snippet but in the browser it completely removes block_two and starts the page on block_three instead and takes away scrolling capabilities because of the fixed position.

Comment: okay.. is it your full code. if not not then can you setup a fiddle or upload it on zippshare.com and send me the link.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using position: fixed on the div I used background-attachment: fixed to hold the image in place and this .